# ¿Como CAMBIAR EL CONTENIDO DE MI HTML después de enviar un fomulario de mi web a mi correo sin tener que recargar la página?

Tags: php, javascript, html

He creado una pagina web que contiene un formulario el cual es enviado a mi dirección de correo.

```
    <form action="" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="clientRequest" id="clientRequest" value="true" />
    <input type="hidden" name="validDate" id="validDate" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" name="optin1" id="optin1" value="true" />

    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="ffield">
                            <label for="firstname">Nombre</label>
                            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="firstname" value="" placeholder="Nombre usuario o empresa" required  />
                        </div>  
                    </div><!-- .col-sm-6 -->
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="ffield">
                            <label for="email">* Correo electrónico</label>
                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="*Correo electrónico" required />
                        </div>                      
                    </div><!-- .col-sm-6 -->
                </div><!-- .row -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="ffield">
                            <label for="firstname">Telefono</label>
                            <input type="text" name="telefono" id="telefono" value="" placeholder="Telefono"    />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                          <label for="comment">Mensaje</label>
                                          <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="mensaje"  placeholder="Escribir consulta" name="mensaje" required></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                <div id="terms">
                    <p class="info">* are required</p>
                    <input type="submit" id="submitbtn" value="enviar" />
                </div>
            </form>
```

Este es mi php

```
<?php
$name=$_POST['nombre'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$telefono=$_POST['telefono'];
$mensaje=$_['mensaje'];

$dest="paul@gmail.com";
$asunto="Contacto ";

$content="De: $name \n ";
$content.="Correo: $email \n";
$content.="Telefono: $telefono \n";
$content.="Mensaje: $mensaje";
mail($dest,$asunto,$mensaje);
?>
```

Mi pregunta es de que manera puedo hacer para que después de enviar el formulario en el propio HTML se modifique y el formulario no aparezca y en cambio aparezca un mensaje tipo (sin recargar la página):

## Gracias por contactarnos

Comment: Para esto necesitas utilizar AJAX, te recomiendo leer sobre la tecnología y aprenderla.

Answer (score 2):

Ya casi lo tienes!!.. haciendo pequeños cambios a tu código puedes lograr lo que deseas, en resumen colocas un `<iframe>` al final del código y direccionas el `<form>` hacia el `<iframe>`, luego en tu código ***php*** agregas una pequeña rutina en ***javascript*** donde envías un `alert()` con el mensaje que tu quieras.

Partiendo del código que has publicado he creado los siguientes ejemplos donde te explico los cambios que debes hacer a tu código para lograr lo que quieres.

Ejemplo: (codigo ***html***)

```
    <form action="" method="post" target="send"><!-- aqui es donde colocas el target a apuntar al iframe -->
    <input type="hidden" name="clientRequest" id="clientRequest" value="true" />
    <input type="hidden" name="validDate" id="validDate" value="" />
                <input type="hidden" name="optin1" id="optin1" value="true" />

    <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="ffield">
                            <label for="firstname">Nombre</label>
                            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="firstname" value="" placeholder="Nombre usuario o empresa" required  />
                        </div>  
                    </div><!-- .col-sm-6 -->
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="ffield">
                            <label for="email">* Correo electrónico</label>
                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" placeholder="*Correo electrónico" required />
                        </div>                      
                    </div><!-- .col-sm-6 -->
                </div><!-- .row -->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <div class="ffield">
                            <label for="firstname">Telefono</label>
                            <input type="text" name="telefono" id="telefono" value="" placeholder="Telefono"    />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                          <label for="comment">Mensaje</label>
                                          <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="mensaje"  placeholder="Escribir consulta" name="mensaje" required></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                <div id="terms">
                    <p class="info">* are required</p>
                    <input type="submit" id="submitbtn" value="enviar" />
                </div>
            </form>
<iframe id="send" style="display:none"></iframe><!-- aqui es donde colocar el iframe al final del codigo, es importante mencionar que el iframe debes colocarlo oculto -->
```

Ejemplo: (codigo ***php***)

```
<?php
$name=$_POST['nombre'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$telefono=$_POST['telefono'];
$mensaje=$_['mensaje'];

$dest="paul@gmail.com";
$asunto="Contacto ";

$content="De: $name \n ";
$content.="Correo: $email \n";
$content.="Telefono: $telefono \n";
$content.="Mensaje: $mensaje";
mail($dest,$asunto,$mensaje);
echo "<script>alert('Gracias por Contactarnos, \n\nPronto le responderemos')</script>";
?>
```

No puedo terminar sin antes mencionar que aunque puedes lograr lo que quieres con pequeños cambios a tu código no deja de ser una forma ortodoxa de hacerlo, lo correcto es utilizar nuevas tecnologías tales como ***ajax*** pero quedara de tu parte elegir la forma de como hacerlo.

Espero esto te sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar ajax de la siguiente manera:

No hace falta que utilices las etiqutas "form"

en html

```
<div id="contenedor">
<input type="" id="nombre">
<input type="email" id="email">
<input type="number" id="telefono">
<textarea id="mensaje" ></textarea>
<button onclick="enviarform()">Enviar</button>
</div>
```

en js

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function enviarform() {

    var nombre=document.getElementById("nombre").value;
    var email=document.getElementById("nombre").value;
    var telefono=document.getElementById("nombre").value;
    var mensaje=document.getElementById("nombre").value;

    var datos='nombre='+nombre+'&email='+email+'&telefono='+telefono+'&mensaje='+mensaje;

  var xmlhttp;
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
       //puedes comentar el alert debajo
       alert('Datos Enviados Correctamente');
       document.getElementById("contenedor").innerHTML="<h3>Datos Enviados Correctamente</h3>";
      }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","http://mipagina?"+datos,true); 
  xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
```

y en php deberas cambiar los $_POST por $_GET:

```
<?php
$name=$_GET['nombre'];
$email=$_GET['email'];
$telefono=$_GET['telefono'];
$mensaje=$_GET['mensaje'];

$dest="paul@gmail.com";
$asunto="Contacto ";

$content="De: $name \n ";
$content.="Correo: $email \n";
$content.="Telefono: $telefono \n";
$content.="Mensaje: $mensaje";
mail($dest,$asunto,$mensaje);
?>
```

Explicando un poco, en la parte de html tienes los inputs a los cuales debes asignarles un **id**, luego debes agregar un botón de enviar con un evento **onclick** el cual activará la función ajax.

En la parte de js esta la función ajax que se activa al hacer click en el botón **enviar** del formulario, primero recolecta los datos del formulario por su **id**, luego los coloca concatenados en la variable **datos**, para poder pasarlos por método GET, luego esta el código que envía los datos, cuando los datos se envíen correctamente saltará un alert y el formulario será remplazado por un mensaje de **Datos Enviados Correctamente**. Y por ultimo, debes colocar la pagina destino de los datos (el action en tu formulario) en "http://mipagina?" pero no te olvides de colocar el **?** al final, esto para mandarlos por el método get.

**Nota:** Este código te permite enviar tu formulario sin recargar tu pagina, lo he probado y funciona, pero ten en cuenta que envía los datos por el método GET, si por alguna razón requieres que tus datos se envíen por método POST, puedes buscar "Como enviar datos por ajax con post".

Espero que te sea de ayuda, saludos.